# Change request URL setting in my Django Project with 'Nginx'

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I am using Django with Nginx and Gunicorn.

When I type in https://DomainName[dot]com in the browser below is the message that I get.

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/
```

Can some one please suggest why is the request URL different to the url typed in browser (https://DomainName[dot]com). I would really appreciate your help.

Below is my 'Nginx' server configuration for my domain.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name DomainName[dot]com;

        access_log off;

       # root /opt/myenv/projects/myproject;

        location /static/ {
            alias /opt/myenv/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
}
```

Below is my Gunicorn Configuration

```
command = '/opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/myenv/projects/myproject'
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
workers = 3
user = 'nobody'
```

EDIT:

Below are a few of the configurations that I've tried:

1. Setting the proxy_pass (within my server block) and bind setting in my Gunicorn configuration to 'http://mydomain[dot]com' and When I visit the url I get

   500 Internal Server Error

   When I check the Error logs for Nginx, below are what I get:

   [alert] 16730#0: *766 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 192.241.xxx.xxx, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://192.241.xxx.xxx:80/", host: "mydomain[dot]com"

   [error] 16870#0: *7 open() "/opt/myenv/static/assets/jqm/js_css/images/ajax-loader.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 183.82.xxx.xx, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /static/assets/jqm/js_css/images/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomain[dot]com", referrer: "http://www.mydomain[dot]com/home/"
2. Setting the proxy_pass (within my server block) and bind setting in my Gunicorn configuration to 'http://mydomain[dot]com:8001' and When I visit the url I get

   ```
   Page not found (404)
   Request Method: GET
   Request URL:    http://mydomain[dot]com:8001/
   ```

What I am trying to achieve is a way to set my request url to 'http://mydomain.com' so that, When I enable OAuth2 for Facebook authentication, the request url is inline with the app's domain setting in Facebook.

Note: For indicating'.' I've used [dot], as Server fault doesn't allow users with less than 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Dear Down voter, please suggest what is wrong with the question, at least I can improve it further. Down voting without any comment doesn't help anyone.

Comment: You most likely need to fix your application/change a setting. Your nginx config looks ok, but your application shouldn't use your app server's url, but your web server's.

Comment: @fuero Thanks you your suggestion, I'll search for a way to do that.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done anything beyond show your error and config. You need to do your own research and troubleshooting and include that in your question.

Comment: @DrewKhoury I've spent nearly a day and a half researching on web, reading through Django book and trying various possible combinations of proxy_pass (server config) and bind (gunicorn config), setting them to mydomain.com:8001, mydomain.com and vice versa, but none of them really helped and my last bet was to post it here. I didn't see it worthwhile for the readers time, to read my research as I didn't find it tangible and felt, I was missing something very obvious. Would appreciate if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you list the things you've tried and any logs that are relevant to the question so that readers aren't kept guessing. Also read this http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django thinks that it's running on `127.0.0.1:8001` because *it is* running on `127.0.0.1:8001`.  The fact that you have an instance of nginx forwarding requests to it doesn't change that.

Have you considered having Gunicorn listen on a UNIX socket and have nginx forward requests to that instead?  This should eliminate the problem as Gunicorn won't be listening on a TCP socket at all.

This can be achieved by modifying the Nginx and Gunicorn configuration as shown below

Nginx Configuration:

```
 upstream app_server {
    server unix:/path/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
 }

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name DomainName[dot]com;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
            alias /opt/myenv/static/;
        }

        location / {

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    proxy_pass http://app_server;
                    break;
                    }
        }
 }
```

Replace `bind` in Gunicorn Configuration to the one shown below:

```
bind = 'unix:/path/gunicorn.sock'
```

Comment: your answer sounds promising, could you please suggest me some online documentation that could guide me to do what you have advised. I've tried searching online, but wasn't successful.

Comment: The Gunicorn documentation covers it.  You bind to a unix socket with Gunicorn, then you list that socket as a server in your upstream block in the nginx configuration.